# how to use FileUtils in Karate?

Tags: karate, writetofile, fileutils

need to convert generate PDF from encoded string and save it as pdf for comparison.

Sample feature file:

```
Feature: Compute All  

Scenario: trial and error
* call read('common.feature')
* def xyz = getMDash( 'my password')
* print xyz
* call read('classpath:/test/java/com/intuit/karate/FileUtils.java')



* def doWork =
"""
function('temp.txt','hello world') {
  var JavaDemo = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.FileUtils');
  var jd = new JavaDemo();
  jd.writeToFile('temp.txt','hello world');  
}
"""

* def result = call writeToFile 'temp.txt','hello world'


* def FileUtils = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.FileUtils')
* def result = FileUtils.writeToFile('temp.txt','hello world')
```

using examples as given.

error in log:

```
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 1.314 sec <<< FAILURE!
* def doWork =(Scenario: trial and error)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: function('temp.txt','hello world') {
  var JavaDemo = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.FileUtils');
  var jd = new JavaDemo();
  jd.writeToFile('temp.txt','hello world');
}
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:115)
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:103)
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:88)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:362)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:284)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:170)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:598)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:524)
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:305)
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.defDocString(StepDefs.java:300)
at ?.* def doWork =(testSuite/users/dummy.feature:11)
**Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException**: <eval>:1:10 Expected ident but found temp.txt
function('temp.txt','hello world')
```

need help on using fileUtils in karate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate does not have any support for writing files because it is bad practice. I have no idea what you are trying to do above. Normally you do your comparison by keeping responses in memory, refer to the file upload example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature

The same example also has an example of using a custom Java class. If you really really need to write something to a file, write your own utility using the above code and using `com.intuit.karate.demo.util.FileChecker` as a reference.

Comment: The json file we are receiving as response, in that payload has one field which is a encoded pdf. This string is changing since it also has date embedded. To check the correctness of this field, i need to decode the string and save it as pdf to compare it with baseline (ignoring date). Unless, there is any other possible way to check it.

Comment: @Shubs - anyway you have to write a custom comparison, sounds like Java code. all you need to do is get the baseline string and then do an equality match with that response field. there is no need to save a file.

Comment: I also need to extract the specific field from response, to do an action on it like decode.

Comment: @Shubs and your question is ? ok but seriously extracting fields into a variable for later checks is one of the core-competencies of karate. look at the examples please. jeez